# Comparing columns in two csv files and writing result to a third

Tags: unix, awk

I have two csv files with the following columns:

alternate.csv:

```
Q P-003430 NO HOUR PARKING 8AM-10PM EXCEPT SUNDAY
```

csvtest.csv:

```
-73.90479333 40.70043234 5597032 P-003430 1010648.808 194477.1977 NO HOUR PARKING 8AM-10PM EXCEPT SUNDAY
```

I used

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$4 in a{print $1}' alternate.csv csvtest.csv >result.csv
```

in order to compare the columns and get the results I want.  However, the last column `NO HOUR PARKING 8AM-10PM EXCEPT SUNDAY` gets cut off to just `NO` in the last column.

For example result.csv comes out as:

```
-73.90479333 40.70043234 5597032 P-003430 1010648.808 194477.1977 NO
```

Is there any way to change that so I would be able to keep the whole phrase `NO HOUR PARKING 8AM-10PM EXCEPT SUNDAY` in the last column.

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited it.  The issue is that the last column gets cut off to just the first number/word.  For example lets say 1 hour parking would get cut off to 1.

Comment: @masterqp Your command should not yield the output you have shown. You are printing `$1` so output should just show `-73.90479333`. If you do `print $0` you should get the entire line. What are we missing?

Comment: Oh thanks that works. I am not sure why $1 gives the result it does. You are right it should only give the first column.

Comment: @masterqp To be one the safer side, make sure your files are not having any special characters. Do `cat -A` on both files and look for any weird characters.

Comment: When you say `the last column gets cut off to just the first number/word` that gives us a clue that your input files are not formatted as you've shown or told us about so far since the files shown have blank chars between each field and the script you posted treats them as such so you can't have a `first number/word` in your `last column`. The other clue is you say they are csv files but there's no comma in sight. Post some truly representative input and tell us what separates your fields if you'd like help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acknowledging from the comments that there is uncertainty as to what format the files actually are and what OP has actually tried, the obvious fix for the surface problem is:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR { a[$2]; next } $4 in a' alternate.csv csvtest.csv
-73.90479333 40.70043234 5597032 P-003430 1010648.808 194477.1977 NO HOUR PARKING 8AM-10PM EXCEPT SUNDAY
```

This might not solve the problem, though, as the files are clearly not actually CSV format and the code in OP is not the code used to generate the example output.